# Como mapear entidade usando o dapper com o postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, ddd, dapper

Estou tendo um grande desafio aqui e não estou conseguindo resolver.

Estou trabalhando com `DDD` e na camada de `Infra` esotu usando `Dapper`

Ao tentar executar o seguinte código no `RepositorioUsuario`:

```
    public long Adicionar(TEntity entity)
    {
        using (var connection = _dbConnectionString.Connection())
        {
            connection.Open();
            return connection.Insert<TEntity>(entity);
        }
    }
```

Erro de mapeamento com a entidade:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '42703: coluna "Nome" da relação "usuario" não existe'

Esse erro ocorre porque na entidade tenho uma propriedade com o nome `Nome` e se eu mudar para `nome` com o "N" minúsculo, o `dapper` consegue mapear.

Mas não quero fazer isso pois quero seguir o padrão dos nomes. Sei que parece bobagem, mas é muito esquisito trabalhar com propriedades com letra minúscula.

Estou quase abandonando o `Dapper` e usando o `ADO` mesmo. Não quero usar o `EF`.

O que devo fazer? tentar corrigir isso? mudar para `ADO`? existe alguma regra que eu não possa usar `ADO` em projetos `DDD`?

Comment: O problema não é o Dapper em si, é a biblioteca que contém o método `Insert`. O PostgreSQL é _case sensitive_, e o insert está sendo escrito com base no nome das propriedades. Você precisa conferir nesta biblioteca se há como configurar o código gerado para adaptar o casing usado.

Comment: Meu problema estava no Dapper.Contrib. Agora estou usando diretamente o Dapper sem nenhuma extensão e deu certo. Obrigado